# $divide aggregation framework questions

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this query for the MongoDB aggregation framework. I cannot figure out why I can't get this query to run. I checked the documentation and am still perplexed. Can anyone let me know what is wrong.

```
 db.acquisitions.aggregate([

{ $match: {"acquired_year":{$gte:1999} }  },
{ $group: {_id:"$acquired_year", "total_acquisition_amount(BBn)": { $divide :[ {$sum:"$acquistion_price"}, 1000000000 ] } }},
{ $sort : {"acquired_year" : -1} }

])
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) manual page, which also lists all valid "accumulators", which means the operators that **must** be the first argument to any field property referenced after the `_id`.

This should then lead you to work out that if you want to [`$divide`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/) on a summed total, you need to place that operation in a separate aggregation pipeline stage with [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/):

```js
db.acquisitions.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "acquired_year":{ "$gte": 1999 } }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id":"$acquired_year", 
        "total_acquisition_amount(BBn)": { "$sum": "$acquistion_price" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "total_acquisition_amount(BBn)": { 
            "$divide": [ "$totatotal_acquisition_amount(BBn)", 1000000000 ] 
        } 
    }},
    { "$sort": { "_id": -1 }}
])
```

The only way you can otherwise use math and other operators is "within" an accumulator like `$sum`, which does not apply in this case since the division must occur "after" the total has been determined.

Also, as a result of `$group`, the "acquired_year" field is no longer part of the document emitted, but instead this is the `_id` value, so you apply the sort on that instead.

Comment: @Yolo49 Welcome to Stack Overlow. Please read what it means to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) here.